# Gridview with dropdown lists edit is not working is restoring the dropdwon lists first value

Tags: asp.net, gridview, edit, dropdown

Hi i am finalized creating the gridview  add, edit, update with drop down lists from inner join tables. Everything is working just in edit is restoring the dropdown lists to their first values and i want when the user press edit to show the name of added value 
Thanks in advance
That is my code:

```
                    <asp:TemplateField >
                         <ItemStyle Width="143px" />
        <HeaderStyle  Width="143px" />
                         <HeaderTemplate >
         <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Customer Name"></asp:Label><br /><br /><br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="fddlCName" Width="145px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5"  DataTextField="Customer_Name"
                        DataValueField="C_ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("C_ID") %>'
                        Runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True"><asp:ListItem Value="-1">---Select Customer---</asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList>
                         </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Customer_Name")%>'> </asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="eddlCName" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5" Width="145px" DataTextField="Customer_Name"
                        DataValueField="C_ID" runat="server" >
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>

                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField >
                 <ItemStyle Width="140px" />
    <HeaderStyle  Width="140px" />
                 <HeaderTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Product"></asp:Label><br /><br /><br />
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="fddlMmodel" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" Width="138px"  DataTextField="Machine_Model"
                    DataValueField="Product_ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Product_ID") %>' AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                    Runat="server"><asp:ListItem Value="-1">---Select Product---</asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList>
                     </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMmodel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Machine_Model")%>'> </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="eddlMmodel" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4"  DataTextField="Machine_Model"
                    DataValueField="Product_ID" Width="138px" Runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>

                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CobornSalesDBConnectionString %>"
 SelectCommand="SELECT distinct Status_ID, Status FROM STATUSES"></asp:SqlDataSource>

         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CobornSalesDBConnectionString %>"
 SelectCommand="SELECT distinct Product_ID, Machine_Model FROM PRODUCTS "></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And my code behind for innerjoining the tables for the gridview

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            userSales();


        }

    }


    private static DataTable GetData(string query)
    {
        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CobornSalesDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void userSales()
    {
        string Agent_ID = Session["Agent_ID"].ToString();
        con.Open();
        if (Session["Agent_ID"] != null)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SalesActivity.A_ID,SalesActivity.Date, SalesActivity.Quatation_Number,CUSTOMER.Agent_ID, CUSTOMER.Customer_Name, PRODUCTS.Machine_Model, SalesActivity.Quantity, 
                SalesActivity.valueGBR, SalesActivity.valueEUR,  SalesActivity.weightedValue, STATUSES.Status, SalesActivity.estDecisionDate, SalesActivity.PromisedDeliveryDate FROM [SalesActivity] 
                INNER JOIN [CUSTOMER] ON SalesActivity.C_ID = CUSTOMER.C_ID INNER JOIN [PRODUCTS] ON SalesActivity.Product_ID = PRODUCTS.Product_ID INNER JOIN STATUSES ON SalesActivity.Status_ID = STATUSES.Status_ID
                where CUSTOMER.Agent_ID = @Agent_ID", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Agent_ID", Agent_ID);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());  // if record not found then returning a blank table structure
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                int columncount = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
                GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
                GridView1.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columncount;
                GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Records Found";
            }
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex; //this open new index that is edit mode
        userSales();
    }  


    protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;   //after cancel button want go to one index back that's y -1
        userSales();
    }
  protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox ftxtvalueGBR = (TextBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("ftxtvalueGBR");

        DropDownList fddlStatus = GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("fddlStatus") as DropDownList;
        TextBox ftxtweightedValue = (TextBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("ftxtweightedValue");


        double weightedValue=0;
        double contractValue = Convert.ToDouble(ftxtvalueGBR.Text);


        if (fddlStatus.SelectedValue == "S00001")
        {
            weightedValue = 0;
        }
        else if (fddlStatus.SelectedValue == "S00002")
        {
            weightedValue = ((contractValue  *  0.25));
        }
        else if (fddlStatus.SelectedValue == "S00003")
        {
            weightedValue = ((contractValue  * 0.50));
        }
        else if (fddlStatus.SelectedValue == "S00004")
        {
            weightedValue = (contractValue);
        }
        else if (fddlStatus.SelectedValue == "S00005")
        {
            weightedValue = 0;
        }
        ftxtweightedValue.Text = weightedValue.ToString();

    }
    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Agent_ID = Session["Agent_ID"].ToString();
        TextBox ftxtDate = (TextBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("ftxtDate");
        TextBox ftxtQno = (TextBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("ftxtQno");
        DropDownList fddlCName = GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("fddlCName") as DropDownList;
        DropDownList fddlMmodel = GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("fddlMmodel") as DropDownList;
        TextBox ftxtQuantity = (TextBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("ftxtQuantity");
        TextBox ftxtvalueGBR = (TextBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("ftxtvalueGBR");
        TextBox ftxtvalueEUR = (TextBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("ftxtvalueEUR");
        TextBox ftxtweightedValue = (TextBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("ftxtweightedValue");
        DropDownList fddlStatus = GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("fddlStatus") as DropDownList;
        TextBox ftxtestDecisionDate = (TextBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("ftxtestDecisionDate");
        TextBox ftxtPromisedDeliveryDate = (TextBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("ftxtPromisedDeliveryDate");


        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SalesActivity( Date, Quatation_Number, C_ID, Product_ID, Quantity, valueGBR, valueEUR, weightedValue, Status_ID, estDecisionDate, PromisedDeliveryDate)  VALUES( @Date, @Quatation_Number, @C_ID, @Product_ID, @Quantity, @valueGBR, @valueEUR,  @weightedValue, @Status_ID, @estDecisionDate, @PromisedDeliveryDate) ", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Parse(ftxtDate.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quatation_Number", ftxtQno.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C_ID", fddlCName.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_ID", fddlMmodel.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", ftxtQuantity.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status_ID", fddlStatus.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estDecisionDate", DateTime.Parse(ftxtestDecisionDate.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PromisedDeliveryDate", DateTime.Parse(ftxtPromisedDeliveryDate.Text));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ftxtvalueGBR.Text))
        { cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@valueGBR", DBNull.Value)); }
        else
        { cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@valueGBR", ftxtvalueGBR.Text)); }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ftxtvalueEUR.Text))
        { cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@valueEUR", DBNull.Value)); }
        else
        { cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@valueEUR", ftxtvalueEUR.Text)); }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ftxtweightedValue.Text))
        { cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@weightedValue", DBNull.Value)); }
        else
        { cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@weightedValue", ftxtweightedValue.Text)); }


        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        if (result == 1)
        {
            userSales();
            Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('" + ftxtQno.Text + "'+' Sale Details inserted successfully');</script>");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('" + ftxtQno.Text + "'+' Sale Details not inserted');</script>");
        }



    }


    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        string Activity_ID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["A_ID"].ToString();
        TextBox etxtDate = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("etxtDate");
        TextBox etxtQno = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("etxtQno");
        DropDownList eddlCName = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("eddlCName") as DropDownList;
        DropDownList eddlMmodel = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("eddlMmodel") as DropDownList;
        TextBox etxtQuantity = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("etxtQuantity");
        TextBox etxtvalueGBR = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("etxtvalueGBR");
        TextBox etxtvalueEUR = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("etxtvalueEUR");
        TextBox etxtweightedValue = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("etxtweightedValue");
        DropDownList eddlStatus = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("eddlStatus") as DropDownList;
        TextBox etxtestDecisionDate = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("etxtestDecisionDate");
        TextBox etxtPromisedDeliveryDate = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("etxtPromisedDeliveryDate");


        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update SalesActivity set Date=@Date,Quatation_Number=@Quatation_Number, C_ID = @C_ID, Product_ID = @Product_ID,Quantity = @Quantity, valueGBR = @valueGBR, valueEUR = @valueEUR, weightedValue = @weightedValue, Status_ID = @Status_ID,estDecisionDate = @estDecisionDate, PromisedDeliveryDate = @PromisedDeliveryDate  where A_ID=@A_ID ", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@A_ID", Activity_ID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Parse(etxtDate.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quatation_Number", etxtQno.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@C_ID", eddlCName.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_ID", eddlMmodel.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status_ID", eddlStatus.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estDecisionDate", DateTime.Parse(etxtestDecisionDate.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PromisedDeliveryDate", DateTime.Parse(etxtPromisedDeliveryDate.Text));

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(etxtvalueGBR.Text))
        { cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@valueGBR", DBNull.Value)); }
        else
        { cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@valueGBR", etxtvalueGBR.Text)); }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(etxtQuantity.Text))
        { cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Quantity", DBNull.Value)); }
        else
        { cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Quantity", etxtQuantity.Text)); }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(etxtvalueEUR.Text))
        { cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@valueEUR", DBNull.Value)); }
        else
        { cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@valueEUR", etxtvalueEUR.Text)); }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(etxtweightedValue.Text))
        { cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@weightedValue", DBNull.Value)); }
        else
        { cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@weightedValue", etxtweightedValue.Text)); }



        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('" + etxtQno.Text + "'+' Details Updated successfully!');</script>");
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        userSales();
    }

    protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

        userSales();
    }

    }
  }
```

Comment: It looks like you have your `DropDownList`s in the `HeaderTemplate`. The header is only calculated once (by default).  To reload those (after insert or update), have you tried reloading those in your codebehind?

Comment: Hi i designed the user to add new records only in the header i will show you the code behind. What you mean reloading the dropdown list after insert ?

Comment: @tgolisch i just added the full code behind can you check. thanks

Comment: autopostback="true"

Comment: @ArunPratap i tried to put for each dropdown list autopostback=true but is still not displaying it. i dont know what to do next and i really need to finish it :(